# Easy USB disk mount command

Tags: mount, usb-drive

In a typical GUI file manager, like PCManFM, I can mount a USB drive by simply clicking on its icon. Is there a similar command I can use which automatically creates a directory in the right place (/media/USER/label) before it mounts the drive? I use Debian 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

udisks2

```
udiskctl mount -b /dev/sdXy
```

Example

```
udiskctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
```

mounts 1. Partition from /dev/sdb

udisks

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdXy
```

Comment: If you update your answer and use `/dev/disk/by-label/LABEL` instead the command will be even easier to use (and you will get more upvotes).

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way in this situation is to use udev. [This](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/) is ready, copy-paste solution:

> Simply create a file
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules with the
>   following:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"  
# Import FS infos  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"  
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"  
# Global mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"  
# Filesystem-specific mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"  
# Mount the device  
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Exit  
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

> Once you have created your script and saved it, reload udev with:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

> Now, when you connect the USB storage device, udev should
>   automatically create a directory under /media with either the device
>   ID, or device label (if you have assigned one), and mount the device.
>   If you disconnect the device, the drive directory (in /media) will be
>   automatically removed.

To get to know more about udev read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev).

Answer (score 0):

That's not the neatest solution, because you are leaving on your machine an empty dir for the label of every device you're going to mount.

However, you could try something like this (warning: I haven't tested it):

```
MYDEVICE=/dev/foo
MYDEVLABEL=$(e2label $MYDEVICE)
mkdir -p /media/$USER/$MYDEVLABEL
mount $MYDEVICE /media/$USER/$MYDEVLABEL
```

Remember to add the necessary options to the `mount` command.

Comment: The corresponding unmount command should of course delete the directory. This is what e.g. PCManFM does.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I like the pure udev answer, there is also a tool called usbmount that you can install by

```
apt-get install usbmount
```

which automount disks and is quite simple to configure through its configuration file.
I prefer no automount at all but some clients ask for it.

Comment: The package *usbmount* is not in Debian 9's standard repositories.

Comment: my bad, it's in wheezy, jessie and sid ...